# Loading big text files

Tags: vb.net

I have to load a textfile into my software, which can be really big (at least 1.5 GB), because I need to read the last line of this file to enumerate some elements with the next part of the script. The needed time can be very long but, sometimes, it is not possible to read the file because of the following error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range.'
```

Is there a way to solve this issue? Or maybe a different - and better - path that I can follow to do what I need?

EDIT I:
Here follows more details:

- I'm generating the aforementioned textfile from a batch-script which is run from the software of mine by pressing a button
- Since I need to read a number contained in the last row of the generated textfile, I'm loading the file into the software, the pressure of a button is needed and for the relative Sub I'm using the following command:

  Dim path as string

  path = "C:\textfile.txt"

  RichTextBox1.LoadFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)

Comment: Not clear. Do you need to read just the *last line*? What is a *line*? Is it a text file? Does it use the classic Line Feed [+ Carriage Return] separator(s)? How many chars in a *line*? Have you tried to seek the end of the file and search backwards, to find the *separator(s)*?

Comment: For lines I mean the rows of the text file. There isn't a fixed number of chars per line and I've never tried to start from the ending of the textfile because I've understood that to work on an external text file it's needed to load it and when I load bigger files, I receive the aforementioned error

Comment: *Row* is not a term that applies. It also doesn't matter whether a line of text (if it's text) is composed by a fixed number of chars. Is it a text file or not? Is this file stored locally or are you receiving a stream? -- *I've understood that to work on an external text file it's needed to load it*: not really. What does *external* mean? --> Do you actually need to read the last line of text only? If it's text, do you know the encoding?

Comment: STEP 1: This textfile is generated from a batch script which is run from a button on the software. STEP2: When I click another button, I have to read the last row of this file.

The path of the file is known. Hoping to have been clearer enough

Comment: Read again my two comments and clarify all those points. Add the details to your question (btw, what generates the file is not relevant, its format and content do matter, as the encoding).

Comment: Thread updated.

Comment: Missing pieces (still assuming it's actually a text file - a file that only contains text): 1. the line separator(s) 2. The encoding.

Comment: I can't understand. I'm looking for the needed line with the following string:
        `Dim str As String
        str = RichTextBox3.Lines(RichTextBox3.Lines.Count - 2)
        Dim itm() As String = str.Trim.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: A) How long are the lines? Read the last amount of bytes corresponding to that, plus a few for just in case, then extract the number. B) A better way would be to write the last line to a separate file in the batch file.

Comment: I've got a couple other questions, maybe you've resolved this now.  1) You've said you need the last line, is there any purpose of the rest of the info in this file?  Since you're generating the file can you limit the source output? 2) Do you actually need to display the contents in a RichTextBox? 3) Why does this data need to be output to a file if a 2nd button is going to display it?  Can you not just go direct to the source to get the data rather than reading it from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the last line of the file...

```
Dim LastLine = File.ReadLines("file.txt").Last()
```

Comment: You have to read the whole file, though. You can open a FileStream, `SeekOrigin.End`, register the file length, `Read()` backwards until you find a `\n` (possibly using a fixed-length buffer), then read an array of bytes sized as `FileLength - LineFeedPosition`.